# Short story about the development and proliferation of AI

Tags: story-identification, short-stories, artificial-intelligence

There's a story I read awhile ago that centered around the development of artificial intelligence. Some large corporation or government makes one, and some hacktivist leaks the code to the public. From there, independent researchers pare down the large model into something more easily run. I think this is a short story, but it's possible this may have been in a book.

As for small details, I think the main AIs were named after something in mythology. I don't think the story was particularly focused on individual characters, more so on larger scale changes. It's likely it was written in the last 10-20 years and involved the models being leaked onto a future internet.

This was most likely a story from the internet, and the AI names were some sort of European, potentially including classical Greece.

I think it was memorable since I work in the computer science industry, and this portrayed a believable proliferation of AI.

Comment: The details here are very sparse. You could improve this question by going through the checklists [here](https://scifi.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9335/how-to-ask-a-good-story-id-question) and editing in any relevant info you can think to add.

Comment: Hi, welcome to SF&F.  Where did you read this?  Online, an anthology, a magazine...?  Where the mythological names Greek, Egyptian, Norse, other, a mix?  Did the AI cause large scale societal changes?  Directly or inadvertently?

Comment: It's not part of the Dune prequels (shudder) is it? If so, it'll be in the [Butlerian Jihad](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dune:_The_Butlerian_Jihad). In this a group of people see society collapsing and create an AI to help them take over society. They, turn themselves into cyborgs called [Titans](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Organizations_of_the_Dune_universe#Titans) named after mythical figures like Xerxes and Agamemnon.

Answer (score 1):

Any chance this is ***[Dreamships](https://www.isfdb.org/cgi-bin/title.cgi?9890)*** (1992) by Melissa Scott?

From [Goodreads](https://www.goodreads.com/en/book/show/836601.Dreamships):

> Dreamships is the story of a freelance space pilot and her crew, who are hired by a rich corporate owner to track down her crazy brother--who just may have created the first sentient Artificial Intelligence.

Been a while since I read it, but I recall bits about the corporation paring the AI down to make it more useful.